# JPA Native query is very slow

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've a parent child relationship between tables in JPA. I've to fetch the parent table records based on a condition in child table. So I've
`String LOOKUPQUERY = "select * from ParentEntity p where p.status_id in (select st.id from status st where st.status ='required') order by created desc"; 
@Query(value = LOOKUPQUERY,nativeQuery=true)
List<parentEntity> requiredLookup();`

This is taking 18 seconds. If I run the same on db it's less than a second. Any suggestion on optimizing this?

Comment: If the database supports some kind of "explain" function or similar query analysis tool, I would spend some time with it.

Comment: Have you tried using JOIN instead of IN?

Comment: and checked the indexing of your tables?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. Only executing the query might be fast, however executing it through hibernate adds object conversion, validation, etc. etc. So comparing plain SQL execution to all what happens within Hibernate is not fair. Also why not write a JPQL and let hibernate bother with the actual SQL.

Comment: Realized that we're using a shared dB which caused that intermittent slowdown. Thanks for the responses